# How to make editable a disabled TextField in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working with JavaFX. I have a disabled TextField.

```
private TextField numberField;
```

How can I make the TextField enable/editable?

I have used:

```
numberField.setVisible(true);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: you call setVisible(boolean) in order to make it visible or to hide it. You can call setEditable(boolean) to make the field editable or not and finally the setDisable(boolean) to make the field unable to be clicked etc. Try them in order to understand better their use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setVisible(boolean)` is used to change visible property but for your case you need those two:

```
numberField.setEditable(true);
numberField.setDisable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
numberField.setEditable(true)
numberField.setDisable(false)
```

[`setEditable(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setEditable-boolean-) will actually make `numberField` edible and [`setDisable(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable-boolean-) will make sure `numberField` is not greyed out.

As the name suggests, [`setVisible(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible-boolean-) will only make the object visible/invisible.